# Visual Studio 2015 running Windows Forms Program's crash verification

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I am facing a very, very strange issue in Visual Studio 2015 RTM, while programming a Windows Forms Application.
My Program class, (entry-point-) Main method has a routine that checks if a certain configuration file exists in the current output folder, alerting an error and forcing an `Environment.Exit(-1)` if otherwise.

[image: Entry point]

I have a UserControl I intend to add to a particular form and... when, **in design time**, I try to add the built component into it, this happens,
[image: Design time Error] crashing the IDE with it.

Please notice that the message alert was created after a generic exception was caught, back at the entry point (the `Log` extension method does it).

I'm running a VS2015 RTM version, along with a fresh-from-update Resharper 9.1.3 and PowerTools. <strike>This issue has not happened in VS 2013 Premium</strike>.

Has anyone here faced something similar?

**UPDATE**

I just realized how confusing a code in a foreign language can be, so I'll try to explain it the best I can, updating the first image.

**UPDATE(2)**

It **has** happened in VS2013 Premium, running a 9.1.2 Resharper and PowerTools. Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE(3)**

This is not an answer: [Catching exception in Main() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720704)

It happens in design time, not in debug mode.